# disable jquery datepicker via knckoutjs radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

The radio option in my application return three values allday, morning and halfday. How can I tie my jquery datepicker as such that it is enabled only when allday is selected.

```
var viewModel = function () {
    this.holidayType = ko.observable();
    this.allday = ko.computed(
        {
            read: function () {
                return this.holidayType() == "allday";
            },
            write: function (value) {
                if (value)
                    this.holidayType("allday");
            }
        }, this);
    this.morning = ko.computed(
     {
    read: function () {
        return this.holidayType() == "morning";
    },
    write: function (value) {
        if (value)
            this.holidayType("morning");
    }
    }, this);
    this.afternoon = ko.computed(
    {
        read: function () {
        return this.holidayType() == "afternoon";
    },
    write: function (value) {
     if (value)
        this.holidayType("afternoon");
    }
    }, this);
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

$(function () {
    $("#e1").daterangepicker({
        datepickerOptions: {
            minDate: 0
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you specify exactly which `daterangepicker` you're using? Googling "daterangepicker" comes up with five different results. It would be especially helpful if you made a MCVE, like a fiddle

Comment: https://github.com/tamble/jquery-ui-daterangepicker

Comment: @blgt the css file is not available as a cdn therefore its not possible to provide a JSFiddle :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I added an observable named `dateRangeButton` to your viewmodel. This observable will hold a jQuery selector to the dynamically generated `<button>` that is created by the date range picker plug-in:

```
this.dateRangeButton = ko.observable();
```

Then I added a function to the viewmodel called `enableDisableDateRange`. When called, this function will add or remove the `disabled` attribute to the date range picker button based on whether or not the `holidayType` equals "allday":

```
this.enableDisableDateRange = function(context) {
    context.dateRangeButton().prop('disabled', context.holidayType() != 'allday');
}
```

How do we get the selector for the date range picker button? I created a custom binding which will apply the date range picker to the element and populate the `dateRangeButton` observable in the viewmodel:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // apply the date range picker
        $(element).daterangepicker({
            datepickerOptions: {
                minDate: 0
            }
        });
        // tell the viewmodel where the date range picker button is
        bindingContext.$data.dateRangeButton($(element).next('button'));
        // enable or disable the button
        bindingContext.$data.enableDisableDateRange(bindingContext.$data);
    }
};
```

I added this binding to the `<input>` element that will contain the date range picker:

```
<input id="e1" name="e1" data-bind="datePicker: ''">
```

Finally, I added a `subscribe` to the `holidayType` observable which will call the `enableDisableDateRange` function any time `holidayType` changes:

```
this.holidayType.subscribe(function() {
    this.enableDisableDateRange(this);
}, this);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cfb1dLg/

NOTE: This all relies on how the date range picker arranges it's UI. Currently, it creates a `<button>` element directly after the `<input>` element it is applied to. If this changes, then the `datePicker` custom binding I wrote would have to be modified as well. The custom binding also assumes the presence of an observable named `dateRangeButton` and a function named `enableDisableDateRange` exist within the viewmodel.